# What's the meaning of RUN mkdir /code and ADD . /code/

Tags: mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm now following instructions of Docker to create a Django+MySQL project. But for the Dockerfile, could any one explain why we have these two lines?

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code  <=====Why we need to mkdir here, will /code dir be delete after build?
RUN mkdir /code/db
WORKDIR /code
ADD ./mysite/requirements.txt /code/  <==For my understanding, here we copy our local requirements file into image's /code dir?
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/  <== What's this step doing? Copying all my current dir's content into /code? why we do this?
```

And in the docker-compose.yml, there are lines like this:

```
web:
  build: .
  command: python ./mysite/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
   < - .:/code > 
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - db
```

Comment: "could any one explain why we have these two lines?" To create the directories.

Comment: @tkausl Yes I know it's used to create dir. But why we need to create such dirs? Will the /code dir be delete after build? Is it a temp dir during building?

Comment: No it won't, unless there is a `RUN rm -rf /code` somewhere later in the dockerfile. "But why we need to create such dirs?" Its where your code (project) lives.

Comment: @tkausl Hi, I edited my question again. And you could see the docker-compose.yml file now. In this file, the line with <> is to mount our local dir . to the image dir /code? Why? Why we do this? My understanding is if we change local dir's content, then it will map to the code dir in image?

Answer (score 4):

```
RUN mkdir /code
```

This line will create a directory under `/` called code. This directory will contain the code which currentlt resides in `.` on the host machine.

```
ADD ./mysite/requirements.txt /code/
```

Add the python requirements.txt from host machine into the `code` directory inside the container.

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Install the requirements inside the container.

```
ADD . /code/
```

Add the python code from the host machine into the container inside `/code` directory

```
volumes:
 < - .:/code >
```

Mount the curent directory on the host onto the containers `/code` directory. You may wonder why do this and the code has already been added via the `ADD . /code/`?

This is a clever technique for developement purposes. Rather than rebuilding the image every time you change in the python code, you can mount the python code and automatically the changes will be visible inside the container. So only restarting the container is needed to have the new code changes.

Comment: great! Thanks yamenk! Many books just tell us how to do but less why to do...Thank you for your explanation!